# Long running callbacks in setInterval get slower and slower

Tags: node.js, mongodb, setinterval

I have this setInterval in an express project:

```js
setInterval(async () => {
  const result = await getData(1000 * 60)
  // send the result to the frontend via socket
  chat.emit('/total/IO/metric/1s', result)
}, 1000)
```

TcpDataDa.getData looks like this:

```js
async function getData(ms) {
 ...
 const start = new Date()

 const resultsFromTcpData = await TcpDataModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        timestamp: {$gte: startMS, $lte: startMS + ms},
      },
    },
  ])

 const end = new Date()
 console.log(end - start)
}
```

TcpDataModel.aggregate gets 120000 pieces of data out of 2400000 from mongodb.
I timed the query (in milisecond):

```
1322
1790
2190
2242
2767
3690
4332
4740
4933
5037
5483
5544
5629
5758
5922
6472
6540
6688
6860
7031
7210
7551
```

The query takes more and more time to finish, but if I set the delay to 2 seconds, like this:

```js
setInterval(async () => {
  const result = await getData(1000 * 60)
}, 2000)
```

The result is:

```
1220
1134
1131
1143
1132
1134
1160
1115
1121
1147
1102
1100
1137
1108
1140
1107
1106
1126
1096
1123
1101
1130
1084
1094
1096
1168
```

1. Why does the query get slower and slower? From my observation, it's possibly because the query takes longer than the delay to finish. A new query starts before the last query ends, so there are more and more queries at the same time? However, I have other similar setInterval running at the same time. Does it mean only when these queries are created by the same timer will cause this problem?
2. How should I solve it? I can't set the delay longer, because I need the data generated in the last second to display some real-time graphs and the data needs to be updated every second.
3. Is it normal for the query to take that amount of time to finish? I run the same query in the MongoDB compass. The explain plan:

```
Explain Plan
Query Performance Summary
Documents returned: 120000

Actual query execution time (ms): 162
Query used the following indexes: 1
> timestamp_1

executionStats:
 nReturned: 120000
 executionTimeMillis: 169
 totalKeysExamined: 120000
 totalDocsExamined: 120000
```

I understand that it's normal it takes longer for queries to finish in the backend than in the database, but is it a bit too long?

In both situations, the cpu is below 80%.

The version of nodejs: 17.9.1, Mongodb: 6

The way fake data is added into the database:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
from config import mongo_uri
import threading
import time

def set_interval(func, sec):
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec)
        func()
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t

client = MongoClient(mongo_uri, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=1)
scapy_database = client['scapy']
writeConcern = pymongo.write_concern.WriteConcern(w=0, wtimeout=None, j=None, fsync=None)
http_data_collection = scapy_database['tcpdatas'].with_options(write_concern=writeConcern)

def current_milli_time():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

def add_data():
    result = http_data_collection.insert_many([{
        "dst_mac": "08:b4:b1:12:b9:14",
        "src_mac": "8c:1d:96:e8:da:d7",
        "src_ip": "192.168.86.22",
        "dst_ip": "104.18.3.164",
        "src_port": 55924,
        "dst_port": 443,
        "packet_size": i,
        "protocols": [
            "UDP"
        ],
        "timestamp": current_milli_time()
    } for i in range(2000) ])

set_interval(add_data, 1)
```

When I timed the functions, I didn't add new data into the database.

Comment: Do you realize that the `await` does you absolutely no good at all?  `setInterval()` pays no attention to the returned promise from your `async` callback so that does you no good at all.

Comment: In the original code, after `getData`, the result was sent to the frontend via socket, so I think it's necessary to use `await` here? I've updated the post. @jfriend00

Comment: Yes, that actually has something executing after the `await`.  My point was the `await` does not help you in the `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theory seems correct.  The query takes longer than 1 second to complete therefore when you start a new query every second, you end up with more and more queries going at once, all slowing each other down.

The better solution here is to find a faster way to determine what is new in your data so you can detect new information much more efficiently (in far less than one second).  We don't know anything about the structure of your data or what exactly you're looking for or how new data gets added to the database.  But, usually the most efficient way to find out about new data is to have the code that adds things to the database simply inform you with some sort of notification about what it added and when.  Then, you don't have to "poll" the database and try to reverse engineer what was just added.

Some databases also have events you can register for when data is inserted.

And, lastly, perhaps structuring indexes and your query appropriately can make your query a lot more efficient.

If you aren't going to pursue a more efficient means of querying or being informed about new relevant data being added to the database, then a stop gap measure is to just not start the next query until the first query has completed so you don't let them accumulate and slow everything down.

```
function pollDatabase(t) {
    // small amount of wait time to allow for some garbage collection
    const minWaitTime = 10;
    const start = Date.now();
    try {
        await getData(...);
    } finally {
        const runTime = Date.now() - start;
        // wait until next schedule period, 
        //   but never wait less than minWaitTime
        const waitTime = Math.max(t - runTime, minWaitTime);

        // schedule next run
        setTimeout(() => { pollDatabase(t) }, waitTime);
    }
}

pollDatabase(1000);
```

Comment: I added the structure of the data and how it's added to the database in the post. I need to get data generated within the last second every second, so it seems I don't need the database to inform me that and the next query must start 1 second after the last query, otherwise the data won't be real-time.

About the index, I have an index on timestamp and for the query in the post, it seems the index is already appropriate. I'm not sure how to make it more efficient.

Comment: @xiyuantu - I'm not experienced with your database so you'll have to find someone who knows that better than I to work on making the query/indexing more efficient.